# I need help to create sql query

Tags: sql, django, database

```
id      | game_id      | point
1       | 100          | 1
2       | 200          | 1
3       | 200          | 0
4       | 300          | 0
5       | 100          | 1
6       | 100          | 1
7       | 200          | 0
8       | 100          | 1
```

I need create a sql query and django query for get logs grouped by local game_id and count the points that correspond to the game_id, it should look something like this

```
game_id      | point
100          | 4
200          | 1
300          | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be simple group by game_id and add up all points for each game_id:

```
select game_id, sum(point) point
from table
group by game_id
```